# HTTP API Rest Controller POST `/api/plugins/rpc/oneway/{deviceId}` RPC calls do not reach the gateway

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

Currently, I have Thingsboard and Thingsboard-gateway running together through the token of the gateway device, I can synchronize extensions via Thingsboard UI and generate new devices through the Thingsboard-gateway in Thingsboard. The problem I have is that rpc calls on the server side by HTTP API Rest Controller POST `/api/plugins/rpc/oneway/{deviceId}` only post the message in the topic `v1/devices/me/rpc/request/+` and they do not reach the Thingsboard-gateway topic for rpc calls on the server side `v1/gateway/rpc`. I have tried to subscribe to the `v1/gateway/rpc` topic and I could not see any messages for what seems to be a Thingsboard error.
Does anyone know what may be happening?

Doc ref:

* https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/

* https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/mqtt/#server-side-rpc-commands

* https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#rpc-api

* https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/#server-side-rpc

Thingsboard version: 2.2.0 release or 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT

Gateway version: 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the gateway did not report the connection message of each device to Thingsboard in topic `v1/gateway/connect"`. So, when thingsboard wanted to send the RPC call to gateway, the Rpc Call didn't reach the gateway.
Therefore, it is necessary that each device is connected through the gateway so that the Rpc call from the side of the Thingsboard works.